# Remove Control from parent UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've already looked around in StackOverflow and the closest question to mine was answered 7 years ago and didn't solve my problem.

```
MainControl.Children.Remove(ChildControl);
```

this does removes the ChildControl from the list of children, but if I check the memory with VS diagnostic tools (namely the 'memory usage' tab) I can see the object still being instanced. I thought the GC would take care of it but if I keep using the application the number of the ChildControl instances, which were supposedly removed, doesn't decrease.

EDIT: I'm writing an extract of the code giving me this problem.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    public ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    // user control
    MainGridUserControl mainGrid;
    SelectionProcess selProcess;

    ProcessManagerViewModel ProcessManagerContext;

    /// <summary>
    /// Switch main grid and selection process. True active main grid, false active selection process
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="openClose"></param>
    public void SwitchMainGridSelectionProcess(bool openClose)
    {
        InfoLoginViewModel ilvm = (InfoLoginViewModel)SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IInfoLoginViewModel>();
        InfoLogin infoLogin = ilvm.ActualInfoLogin;

        // if openClose true close selection process user control and open main grid user control
        // else close main grid user contorllo and return to selection process user control
        if (openClose)
        {
            MainWindowGrid.Children.Remove(selProcess);
            SelectionProcessViewModel spvm = (SelectionProcessViewModel)selProcess.DataContext;
            spvm.CloseCommand.Execute(null);
            selProcess = null;

            mainGrid = new MainGridUserControl(mwvm.LayoutMainGridTop, mwvm.ShowStationTree);
            Grid.SetRow(mainGrid, MAINGRID_ROW);
            if (this.FindName("MainWindowGrid") is null)
                this.RegisterName("MainWindowGrid", mainGrid);

            MainWindowGrid.Children.Add(mainGrid);

            mwvm.SetOpenProcessToggleButtonCommand.Execute(null);

            // set permission process user
            mwvm.SetEnableButtonCommand.Execute(infoLogin.ProcessUser);
        }
        else
        {
            // if maiGrid null the open process failed. The old selProcess is already present
            if (mainGrid != null)
            {
                if (!(this.FindName("MainWindowGrid") is null))
                    this.UnregisterName("MainWindowGrid");
                MainWindowGrid.Children.Remove(mainGrid); // snapshot diagnostic tool shows this line has no effect on the number of instances of 'mainGrid'
                mainGrid = null;

                selProcess = new SelectionProcess();
                Grid.SetRow(selProcess, MAINGRID_ROW);

                MainWindowGrid.Children.Add(selProcess);

                // set permission application user
                mwvm.SetEnableButtonCommand.Execute(infoLogin.ApplicationUser);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Am I supposed to write the dispose method myself? It's not among those suggested by intellisense.

Comment: @V.Leon Sadly no, I'd like to check if (as HenkHolterman) the remove method does is job and the memory windows is just not the right tool to use in this case.
EDIT: I realized I didn't fully answer your question. I can't provide an example since there is not much else except what i've already described, it's simply a line of code which looks like isn't working the way I assumed it would.

Comment: Try GC.Collect() if you really want to collect all the memory as soon as the objects are disposed, which is gen not the case.

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota - no, __do not call `GC.Collect()`__. Far too many problems started that way.

Comment: @HenkHolterman only if it’s absolutely necessary to reclaim the memory occupied by those disposed objects

Comment: I felt like it would be an overkill honestly, moreover it has to be a better way to solve something this simple... Am I wrong in assuming the number of instances should decrease if I remove the childControl  and overwrite the reference pointing at it?

Comment: @FabianoGaeta Yes, the controls should be eligible for garbage collection if there are no references left. Could provide an example code? I suspect there is something still referencing the controls. There should be no need for calling `Dispose` or `GC.Collect()` either.

Comment: Also taking memory snapshot by performance profiler/diagnostic tools will trigger garbage collection (memory/heap profiling is based on events raised by GC) so there is no need to do that manually.

Comment: @V.Leon I've edited my question with the code I've been having trouble with. Hopefully it will be enough.